# Secondary save method in a Spring Data JPA repo?

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Data JPA repo exported via Spring Data REST and secured with Spring Security. I also need to save data to this table from an unsecured endpoint but my `save()` method is secured.

I cannot create a second repository because of https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-923.

The only way I know of is manipulating the security context by hand every time before calling the secured `save()` method.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you secured only `save` method you can try to use insecurely [saveAndFlush](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAndFlush-S-) method.

Another approach - [customize your repo](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior). First - implement the custom repo, for example:

```java
public interface CustomRepo {
    MyEntity saveUnsecured(MyEntity entity);
}

@Repository
public class CustomRepoImpl implements CustomRepo {

    private final EntityManager em;

    public CustomRepoImpl(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public MyEntity saveUnsecured(MyEntity entity) {

        if (entity.getId() == null) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Then extend your repo from custom one:

```java
public interface MyEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, CustomRepo {
    //...
}
```